# Angular directive template is not compiled by outer directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple tags:

```
<form show-errors>
    <date-input />
</form>
```

as You can imagine I have two directives: showErrors and dateInput.

showErrors should work on DOM that is loaded by dateInput template but that never happens :(
showErrors runs (DOM is empty) and after that dateInput loads its template but it's way too late. I have impresion that im using directives in wrong way :(

Please take a look at my plunker for details:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3QEd1HvJETo30tZd1zl3

**Update:**
I updated my plunker and it seams that it's all about lazy loaded template from URL. Any ideas how that should be solved in angular clean way ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a typo in the directive's name: instead of `dateinput` there should be  `dateInput`.

However, it is impossible to refer to the children from the parent in directives. Only communication in the other direction is allowed (usually using controllers).

Comment: Plunker fixed. Can You elaborate more about that ?

Comment: Watch this: [Egg Head's short tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You're making two mistakes.

First, your inner directive should be named dateInput:

```
app.directive('dateInput', function() {
```

Second, you need to explicitly close the date-input tag.

```
<date-input></date-input>
```

It's important to note, that the AngularJS compiler does cannot parse

```
<date-input />
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Please take a look at fixed plunker